# Insert child item to dict() in QAbsrtactItemModel

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtreeview, qabstractitemmodel

I have the next QJsonTreeItem with insertChildren() function::

```
class QJsonTreeItem(object):
    ...
    def setData(self, column, value) -> None:
        if column is 0:
            self.key = value
        if column is 1:
            self.value = value

    def insertChildren(self, position, rows, columns) -> bool:
        if position < 0 or position > len(self._children):
            return False

        for row in range(rows):
            data = [None for v in range(columns)]
            item = QJsonTreeItem(data, self)
            self._children.insert(position, item)

        return True
```

With the next QJsonTreeModel insertRows() and setData() functions:

```
class QJsonTreeModel(QAbstractItemModel):
    ...
    def insertRows(self, position: int, rows: int, parent: QModelIndex) -> bool:
        parent_item = self.getItem(parent)

        self.beginInsertRows(parent, position, position + rows - 1)
        success = parent_item.insertChildren(position, rows, self._root_item.columnCount())
        self.endInsertRows()

        return success

    def setData(self,
            index: QModelIndex,
            value: str=None,
            role: Qt.ItemDataRole=Qt.EditRole
            ) -> bool:
        if role == Qt.EditRole:
            item = index.internalPointer()
            item.setData(index.column(), value)
            self.dataChanged.emit(index, index, [Qt.EditRole])
            return True
        if role == Qt.DecorationRole:
            item = index.internalPointer()
            item.setData(0, value)
            item.setData(1, "[No string value]")
            self.dataChanged.emit(index, index, [Qt.EditRole])
            return True
        if role == Qt.ToolTipRole:
            item = index.internalPointer()
            item.setData(0, value)
            item.setData(1, int(1))
            self.dataChanged.emit(index, index, [Qt.EditRole])
            return True
        if role == Qt.StatusTipRole:
            item = index.internalPointer()
            item.setData(0, value)
            item.setData(1, False)
            self.dataChanged.emit(index, index, [Qt.EditRole])
            return True
        if role == Qt.WhatsThisRole:
            item = index.internalPointer()
            item.setData(0, "[No dict() name]")
            item.setData(1, dict())
            self.dataChanged.emit(index, index, [Qt.EditRole])
            return True
        if role == Qt.SizeHintRole:
            item = index.internalPointer()
            item.setData(0, "[No list() name]")
            item.setData(1, list())
            self.dataChanged.emit(index, index, [Qt.EditRole])
            return True
        return False
```

In my MainWindow file I insert data like this:

```
def tree_add_item(self, role: Qt.ItemDataRole) -> None:
    index = self.tree_view.selectionModel().currentIndex()
    parent = index.parent()

    if self.model.data(parent, Qt.EditRole) is None:
        if not self.model.insertRow(index.row() + 1, parent):
            return

        for column in range(self.model.columnCount(parent)):
            child = self.model.index(index.row() + 1, column, parent)
            if role == Qt.DecorationRole:
                self.model.setData(
                    index=child,
                    value="[No string key]",
                    role=role)
                return
            elif role == Qt.ToolTipRole:
                self.model.setData(
                    index=child,
                    value="[No int data]",
                    role=role)
                return
            elif role == Qt.StatusTipRole:
                self.model.setData(
                    index=child,
                    value="[No bool data]",
                    role=role)
                return
            elif role == Qt.WhatsThisRole or Qt.SizeHintRole:
                self.model.setData(index=child, value=None, role=role)
                # self.action_save_json_file()
                # self.action_refresh_json_file()
                return
            else:
                return

def tree_add_item_child(self, role: Qt.ItemDataRole) -> None:
    index = self.tree_view.selectionModel().currentIndex()
    parent = index

    if not self.model.insertRow(0, parent):
        return

    for column in range(self.model.columnCount(parent)):
        child = self.model.index(0, column, parent)
        if role == Qt.DecorationRole:
            self.model.setData(
                index=child,
                value="[No string key]",
                role=role)
        elif role == Qt.ToolTipRole:
            self.model.setData(
                index=child,
                value="[No int data]",
                role=role)
        elif role == Qt.StatusTipRole:
            self.model.setData(
                index=child,
                value="[No bool data]",
                role=role)
        elif role == Qt.WhatsThisRole or Qt.SizeHintRole:
            self.model.setData(
                index=child, 
                value=None, 
                role=role)
            # self.action_save_json_file()
            # self.action_refresh_json_file()
```

The problem is it successfuly adds new dict() or list() to the QTreeView like this

[image: New dict() added]

I want to add new child items, which my programm successfully adds

[image: New child string]

But when I`m saving back model to the file there is no recently added child string

[image: No child string]

Am I doing something wrong or it should work like this? At the moment my solution is to save back to the .json file new added dict() or list() and then load it againg to the QTreeView (commented lines: self.action_save_json_file() and self.action_refresh_json_file()). It`s working but it seems like a bad idea since not every user want to save immediately new added dict() or list(). Where am I wrong and how to solve this problem?

**Update:**
My method for getting json from tree is this. It generates dict() from tree which I`m saving to some file.

*Small clarification:* after saving json to file and loading it back to QTreeView I`m able to add child elements to recently added dict() or list()  and they can be edited or removed

```
    def get_json_from_tree(self, root: QJsonTreeItem=None) -> dict:
        root = root or self._root_item
        return self.generate_json_from_free(root)

    def generate_json_from_free(self, item) -> dict:
        amount_of_child = item.childCount()

        if item.type is dict:
            document = {}
            for i in range(amount_of_child):
                child = item.child(i)
                document[child.key] = self.generate_json_from_free(child)
            return document
        elif item.type == list:
            document = []
            for i in range(amount_of_child):
                child = item.child(i)
                document.append(self.generate_json_from_free(child))
            return document
        else:
            return item.value
```

Comment: And how are you saving the model? Because it seems clear that the issue is there. Please provide an *actual* [mre] (and ensure that you make it *actually minimal*).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual problem was that my `generate_json_from_free()` function did not catch `QJsonTreeItem.type` of newly added dictionary or list. `item.type` returned `None` and iti s simply did not enter to the `if` section.

The solution is to set type of the QJsonTreeItem when user wants to add dict() or list() like this:

```
self.model.getItem(child).type = dict
```

for dict() and for list() is this:

```
self.model.getItem(child).type = list
```

The complete code is this:

```
def tree_add_item(self, role: Qt.ItemDataRole) -> None:

    if self.model.data(parent, Qt.EditRole) is None:
    if not self.model.insertRow(index.row() + 1, parent):
        return

    for column in range(self.model.columnCount(parent)):
        child = self.model.index(index.row() + 1, column, parent)
        if role == Qt.DecorationRole:
            self.model.setData(
                index=child,
                value="[No string key]",
                role=role)
            return
        elif role == Qt.ToolTipRole:
            self.model.setData(
                index=child,
                value="[No int data]",
                role=role)
            return
        elif role == Qt.StatusTipRole:
            self.model.setData(
                index=child,
                value="[No bool data]",
                role=role)
            return
        elif role == Qt.WhatsThisRole:
            self.model.setData(index=child, value=None, role=role)
            self.model.getItem(child).type = dict
            return
        elif role == Qt.SizeHintRole:
            self.model.setData(index=child, value=None, role=role)
            self.model.getItem(child).type = list
            return
        else:
            return
```